# How to architect scheduled tasks in a message based architecture?

Tags: architecture, scheduled-tasks, nservicebus, servicebus

I have an order web service that has a method for creating orders. When the method is invoked, a message is send to the service bus and gets handled by an order message handler.

On a daily and monthly basis I have to generate an order report. Normally I would have the order message handler storing the order in the database and then have a scheduled task that reads from the database and generates a report. But I was wondering if there is a more message oriented way of doing this?

I thought about having the order message handler publishing a message that various reporting services (e.g. daily and monthly) can subscribe to. The messages would be accumulated on a given queue until the services are activated at given intervals (daily / monthly). The services would then process messages on their queue and generate a report. Is this the way to go or am I way off?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Update

Is it (with NServiceBus) possible to keep messages in a publisher queue and then only publish them at a given interval? Or should it be the other way around so the publisher publishes immediately and the handling by the subscriber is scheduled?

Comment: Have you considered talking to your business stakeholders, telling them that with your message-driven architecture you are now able to do "real-time" reporting rather than daily/monthly. The reason for doing reporting only occasionally is that it degrades the performance of systems built with synchronous architecture.

Comment: If you really need scheduled events, use Quartz Scheduler. MassTransit has an adapter, I bet someone had done the same for NServiceBus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NServiceBus implements a concept called *Sagas* for long-running processes. Have a look at http://nservicebus.com/Sagas.aspx I think the *Timeout* section refers to what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I have looked into sagas but not quite sure yet if that is the way to go.

Comment: With sagas you can set a timeout that will summon the saga to do whatever should be done after a given amount of time has elapsed. you could also use an external timing library, like Quartz.net, to have it send messages at a given time or interval. But I'd prefer the built-in mechanisms of NSB since you're using it already.

Answer (score 1):

Service Bus itself supports scheduled messages, where you can set the ScheduledEnqueueTime and the message will be made available then. That way you can use it to time/schedule events. The details on this property are available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc.aspx